# How make Subscription type of payment using flutter stripe?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am able to make payments of one time using flutter_stripe but how to make subscription type of payment?

I have tried doing it through api's provided by stripe but all in vain, help me how to do it with package flutter_stripe.

Comment: Before you go any further, is the subscription for a real-world service, like a gym membership or a monthly cheese delivery or for a service delivered in your app?  If it is a service in your app then you almost certainly need to use Apple/Google in app purchases, not Stripe.

Comment: It is for service delivered for my app. What to do now? How to use Apple/Google in app purchase?